# How to remove all the values in a string except for the chosen ones

Tags: python, string

So my code is 
`value = "123456"`
I want to remove everything except for 2 and 5. 
the output will be `25`
the program should work even the value is changed for example
`value = "463312"`
the output will be 2

I tried to use `remove()` and `replace()` function. But it didn't work. 
**Doing it on python 3.6.2**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of trying to remove every unwanted character, you will be better off to build a whitelist of the characters you want to *keep* in the result:

```
>>> value = '123456'
>>> whitelist = set('25')
>>> ''.join([c for c in value if c in whitelist])
'25'
```

Here is another option where the loop is implicit.  We build a mapping to use with `str.translate` where every character maps to `''`, unless specified otherwise:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(str, str.maketrans('25', '25'))
>>> '123456'.translate(d)
'25'
```

Comment: Is there any way to use if elif      for example if value == 2 or value == 5            return ""

Comment: Is there any solution using regex ?

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar check out my answer if you are looking for a regex solution.

Comment: Since OP is using Python 3, it would be faster with the brackets "[]" removed. Unsure if single unparenthesized generator comprehension is supported in Python 2.

Comment: @EnricoBorba That's incorrect.  Using the intermediate list comprehension is actually faster, because the generator version adds some unnecessary overhead.  Time it yourself, if you don't believe me.

Comment: @wim You are correct! I just timed it. I really didn't know this. Looks like intermediate list is better even for large strings. Very strange.

Answer (score 9):

In case you are looking for regex solution then you can use `re.sub` to replace all the characters other than `25` with `''`.

```
import re
x = "463312"
new = re.sub('[^25]+' ,'', x)
x = "463532312"
new = re.sub('[^25]+' ,'', x)
```

Output: 
    `2`, `522`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 2, you can use filter like this:

```
In [60]: value = "123456"

In [61]: whitelist = set("25")

In [62]: filter(lambda x: x in whitelist, value)
Out[62]: '25'
```

If you are using Python 3, you would need to `"".join()` the result of the filter.

Comment: ;p kind of the same as my answer. Still, I didn't know you don't have to `list()` the string!

Comment: You don't, that's what makes filter attractive in this case ;).

Comment: Don't you need to `str.join` the result, though? In Python 3, `filter` just returns a lazy `filter` object.

Comment: @Akavall This answer assumes python2, a bad assumption to make.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
value="23456"
j=""
for k in value:
    if k=='2' or k=='5':
        j=j+k
print (j)
```

It is the woorking program of what you said, You can give any input to the value, it will always print 25.

Comment: It doesn't work. Did you even run ?

Comment: @MD.Khairul Basar i mistyprd it before but now i edited it and it works....try it.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar reply if you tried this one and it worked.

Comment: Yes, now it will work. But OP can't use for loop. Read comments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to approach this differently using the Python built-in `filter()` method with `lambda`. See below:

```
a = "1225866125" # Should return "22525"
whitelist = '25'

# Use filter to remove all elements that does not match the condition
a = "".join(filter(lambda c: c in whitelist, a))
```

Hope this helped!

(Edited to shorten the answer, credit @Akavall + again @salparadise)

Comment: `whitelist = '25'` works as well, no need for the tuple.

Comment: Making `whitelist` a `set`, though would be faster (for large white lists).

Answer (score 0):

```
value = "123456"

whitelist = '25'

''.join(set(whitelist) & set(value))
'25'
```

Comment: if `value="1122355"`, will it work ?

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar define 'work' ?

Comment: if `value="1122355"` will it give output `2255` ?

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar I didn't see that requirement in the question.

Comment: @salparadise _"I want to remove everything except for 2 and 5."_ What do you think that means?

Comment: Also, sets are not ordered, so you might up with any order of 2 and 5.